# Update record with Entity FrameWork 7.New record on update

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've started learning Asp.net last weak(I don't have any prior experience with .net), but I've been having some trouble updating a database record.

I have seen only one similiar question([How to update record using Entity Framework 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457128/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-7)), but it did not use forms or controllers, so it wasn't of much help.

I have an object

```
namespace Daycare.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public Question() {

        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get;set;}

        public string question { get; set; }

        public string answer { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller and views were generated automatically.

The delete and create work fine, but the the edit methods only create new,empty objects.

```
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        Question question = _context.questions.Single(m => m.id == id);
        if (question == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(question);
    }

    // POST: Questions/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Edit(Question question)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
//stuff i've tried.
        //    _context.questions.Update(question);

                _context.Update(question);
  //          _context.Entry(question).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(question);
    }
```

This is the form

```html
<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Question</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="id" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="question" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="question" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="question" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="title" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="title" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: '   Question q = new Question();
        int b =  integer(question.id);
               int _a =5007;         
                q.id = _a;
               _context.questions.Attach(question);
                    _context.Entry(question).State = EntityState.Modified;
                     _context.SaveChangesAsync();

'
This seems to be working, but I get an error when
_a = question.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of your input you just need to specify name and id attribute with respective matching property of your question class for example.

OR
or you can use htmlhelper for input, label...
for input text

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
```

for input label

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)
```

so question class takes value when firing submit and call Edit method.

```
//_context.Update(question); //instead of this you can use 

_context.Entry(question).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't quite understood the part on specifying.
Could you please provide an example?

Comment: This seems to be working, but when i set q.id = question id
i get - InvalidOperationException: The property 'id' on entity type 'Question' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'. 
       Question q = new Question();
                    q.id = 5007;
                    q.question = "WILL IT WORK";
                    _context.questions.Attach(q);


                    _context.Entry(q).State = EntityState.Modified;
                     _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");

Comment: you can get edit question id to change code in view instead of **<input type="hidden" asp-for="id" />** set to **<input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" asp-for="id" />**  or you can use html helper like **@HiddenFor(model => model.Id)** so when Edit is fire it take question.id value from hidden model.

Answer (score 1):

Try uncommenting the line

```
 _context.Entry(question).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

This line forces entity framework to mark the object as modified and will run the update command on the object during the savechanges() call

Comment: Thabk you for your reply,

I get an error temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'.




if I set a static value to the Id - It works. Example
  Question q = new Question();
               int _a =5007;
                q.id = _a;
IF
q,id = question.id - Error.
If the id remains unchanged I get an error above.